# Not able to create vcard of contacts using contact framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact

I am using this code to export contact from ios phonebook to .vcf file. I have used this code for the task. But `vcardString` is always returning `nil`. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
NSMutableArray *contacts=[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSError *fetchError;
    CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

    BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {
        [contacts addObject:contact];
    }];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
    }

    // you can now do something with the list of contacts, for example, to show the names

    CNContactFormatter *formatter = [[CNContactFormatter alloc] init];

    for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {

        [contactsArray addObject:contact];
        // NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];

        //NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
    }

    //NSError *error;
    NSData *vcardString =[CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:contactsArray error:&error];

    NSLog(@"vcardString = %@",vcardString);
}];
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Which line seems to be causing issue?

Comment: @Larme I have edited my question.

Comment: You have an `NSError` parameter in `dataWithContacts:error:` class method of `CNContactVCardSerialization`. Check for its value?

Comment: @Larme : It showing this error : "Exception writing contacts to vCard (data): A property was not requested when contact was fetched"

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code line by line and check each value.  Is `request` valid? Does `contacts` end up with one or more contacts? Is there any error from `enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest`? Does `contactsArray` have the expected contacts in it? Why is an `NSData` variable named `vcardString`?

Comment: @rmaddy : There is no error in enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest and contactsArray also has array of contacts.

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact output of the `NSLog(@"error = %@", error);` after the call to `dataWithContacts:error:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

`CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[[CNContactVCardSerialization descriptorForRequiredKeys]]`

This fetches all required info for creating a vCard.